# Droid Naksh Arabic and Numerals

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I want to use [Droid Naskh](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/#hg/apache/droidarabicnaskh%253Fstate%253Dclosed) font in my application. The Arabic letters display beautifully, but the numbers appear as 12345 rather than ١٢٣٤٥.

How do I get the numbers to display as ١٢٣٤٥?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you need to replace the 12345 digits you're displaying with the equivalent Arabic numerals, as listed in the Unicode standard http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf

e.g.

```
U+0660 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT ZERO
....
U+0669 ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT NINE
```